# How do I pass the primary key from one model to another model and display some fields of the first model in the template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have 2 models, 'Candidate' and 'Tracker' .
I want to add the candidates to the tracker list if I wish to. The tracker has some additional fields. However in the tracker template I wish to display some details of the candidate like name, phone etc.
Basically the tracker page contains added candidates with some extra details about them.

Candidate models.py

```
class Candidate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    current_company = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    current_designation = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.candidate_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('candidate-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Tracker models.py

```
class Tracker(models.Model):
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    position_applied = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    current_CTC = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    expected_CTC = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.position_applied

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('tracker-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

views.py files..

```
class TrackerCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Tracker
    fields = ['current_CTC', 'expected_CTC', 'position_applied', 'candidate']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

```
class CandidateCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Candidate
    fields = ['name', 'phone', 'email','current_company', 
    'current_designation']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Until now I have just included candidate as a foreign key. But this requires selecting the candidate name from the dropdown which is not practical.
How can I display the name, phone, email etc. in the tracker list?

I have a button on the candidate page  **'Add to tracker'**  against each name, which opens the Tracker CreateView form and lets me fill and submit the details.Is there any way to auto populate the form with some enteries?
Or what other approach can I go for? Maybe passing the primary key or something? What all changes to make in the urls.py file?

**Note** - I have changed `candidate_name` to `name` in Candidate model and changed `candidate_name` to `candidate` in Tracker model as naming was incorrect and confusing.
However, the answers below are based on the previous naming convention only.

Comment: Note unrelated to your questions: In your `Tracker` model, the `related_name` for `candidate` field is wrong, it should be `trackers`. This is used for the reverse relationship (`candidate.trackers`) and calling it `candidates` would be strange: you'd have to call `candidate.candidates` to get all the trackers for that candidate.

Comment: Note2: Naming the field `candidate_name` in the `Tracker` model for the fk is also confusing. `tracker.candidate_name` returns a `Candidate` instance, not the candidate's name. Also `candidate_name` in `Candidate` is making things complex. To get the name you now need to do `tracker.candidate_name.candidate_name` which is hard to read and makes little grammatical sense. You want `tracker.candidate.name`. Change your field names to `candidate` and `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**: How to customise the display of the dropdown to select the `Candidate`?

You need to override the actual form field used for `candidate_name`. By default this is a `ModelChoiceField`, which has a method [`label_from_instance()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.to_field_name) that you can override to decide what to display (instead of just the name):

1. Subclass `ModelChoiceField` and override just `label_from_instance()`
2. Subclass `ModelForm` to override just the `candidate_name` field, as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields)
3. Add this class as `form_class` to your `CreateView`

**Question 2**: How to pre-populate the `TrackerCreateView`?

[Here](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/)'s a very useful reference for Django generic CBVs. You will see that the `CreateView` has a `get_initial()` method that you can use to populate the form with initial values (just pass it a dictionary with values). The first request to your `CreateView` is a GET request, so you just need to pass URL query parameters to give the view some additional information. So in your case:

1. Add the query parameters to the URL calling the `TrackerCreateView`, e.g. in your button template:

   ```
   <a href="{% url 'tracker-create' %}?candidate_id={{ candidate.id }}">
   ```
2. Override the `get_initial()` method in your `TrackerCreateView`. `self.request.GET` will be a dictionary containing your URL query parameters:

   ```
   def get_initial(self):
       initial = super().get_initial()
       candidate_id = self.request.GET.get('candidate_id')
       if candidate_id:
           try:
               candidate = Candidate.objects.get(id=candidate_id)
           except Candidate.DoesNotExist:
               pass
           else:
               initial.update({'candidate_name': candidate})
       return initial
   ```
3. Now your form will be prefilled with the candidate.

Comment: ```<a href="{% url 'tracker-create' %}">``` This is my url as of now. 
This is just a link mentioned alongside every candidate name in my html table. 
How does the url know which candidate I'm referring to? 

Or should I shift this link to my Candidate-Detail page having the path- 
```path('candidate/<int:pk>/', CandidateDetailView.as_view(), name='candidate-detail'),```

Comment: you said `{% url 'tracker-create' %}` worked before. That's why I suggested to use query parameters (?param=value). If you change the url pattern, of course you also need to add the required parameters.

Comment: With you current url pattern, the object.id is passed as `pk` kwarg to your view, i.e. you can retrieve it with `self.kwargs['pk']` (rather than `request.GET`).

Comment: prepopulate where? your tracker form doesn't have these fields.

Comment: Ignore the above messages. My internet connection was slow and i thought messages didn't get delivered. I made the changes back. It worked !! Wow, such a relief. I have to pre-populate email and phone number as well. Assuming I have added them as a foreign key too, what changes should I make to the get_initial method?

Comment: email and phone aren't foreign keys, they are just fields of the `Candidate` model. So I don't understand where you want to prepopulate them since your tracker form doesn't have these fields.

Comment: but `candidate_name` is a field of `Tracker`. I don't see `email` and `phone`. They cannot be in the tracker form since they are not fields of `Tracker`.

Comment: I had "candidate_name" as a foreign key to the tracker model. And after your solution it's showing in the tracker form and getting autofilled too. 
But I want to do the same with email and phone as well.

```return {'candidate_name': candidate}```
Can I append those fields in this code? 
Separated by a comma or something?

Comment: That's what. Let's say I add them too in the tracker.

Comment: You just need to return a dictionary. So that can contain values for any number of fields.

Comment: How do I do that? 
Actually my ultimate goal is to display the candidate name, phone and email in the tracker html table after it is added. 
Since candidate_name is a field of tracker model, I can simply call it.
But phone and email are not. 

So I thought of making those also as fields in tracker and giving pre-populating them as I have done now for candidate_name.

Comment: [python dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: But if you just need to display a value (rather than a field) in your template, then add it to the context, overriding `get_context_data` rather than `get_initial`. `get_initial` if for setting initial values for the form fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You cleared so many doubts. 
I won't prefer to just display the field values.

Rather I shall create 2 more fields in the tracker model. 'phone' and émail'. 
I actually tried that. But I can't once again specify them as foreign key. That's against the syntax. So what do i do?
Let's say I just add them as CHAR fields. 

How do I pre-populate the form now with phone and email of the same candidate whose name I have pre-populated? 
Last question, i won't trouble you after this I promise. XD

Comment: if they are just char fields on the tracker form, you can prepopulate them in get_initial like you did with the candidate_name field: `'email': candidate.email`. As I said your `get_initial()` method should return a dictionary with the initial values for the various fields (any number of them).